# How should i use sqlalchemy to access the schema

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a file called models.py in which i state:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Vehicle(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'vehicle'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String(15), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String(100), default='')
    vehicletype_id = ForeignKey('VehicleType.id')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Which creates the database tables in my PostgreSQL database.

In my app.py should i now use:

```
from models.py import Vehicle

<do something with the Vehicle object>
```

or should i use something like:

```
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
vehicle = meta.tables['vehicle']
```

when i want to access the schema of the table and the data in the database in that table.

I want to be able to create an API call (flask-jsonrpc) that gives the schema of a table , and another API call that returns the data from that table in the PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using declarative ORM approach (by declaring your Vehicle class), there is no point to reflect it. Reflection is normally used when you're dealing with existing database and advanced features (such as defining custom relationships) are not important to you.